# getting an error Object doesn't support property or method 'setSrc' in web Resource in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, onload

I have used the WebResource on the Page and I am getting an error Object doesn't support property or method 'setSrc' in Javascript

Can you Please help me

My actual code is like this

```
function getImage()
{
var entityId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var profilePictureElement = Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource_ProfilePicture");
if (entityId) {
    var oDataQuery = getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc" +
        "/AnnotationSet?$top=1&$select=AnnotationId,DocumentBody,MimeType&" +
        "$orderby=ModifiedOn desc&$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'" + entityId +
        "' and IsDocument eq true and Subject eq 'Profile Picture'" +
        " and startswith(MimeType,'image/') ";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: oDataQuery,
        beforeSend: function (request) { request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
        success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                var mimeType = data.d.results[0].MimeType;
                var body = data.d.results[0].DocumentBody;
                // set src attribute of default profile picture web resource.
                // here we use DataURI schema which has 32kb limit in IE8 and doesn't support IE <= 7.
                profilePictureElement.setSrc("data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + body);

            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, exception) { }
    });
  }
}
function getServerUrl()
{
var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
// trim trailing forward slash in url
return serverUrl.replace(/\/*$/, "");
}
```

you can refer the whole article from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/09/28/displaying-a-contact-s-facebook-picture-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Comment: Hi @Kartik check the value of profilePictureElement

Comment: Pedro Azevedo : I have checked the value of it and i got the webresource correctly in profilePictureElement but dont know why that happened?

Comment: How do you know you got it correctly?

Comment: @James Wood : using debugger..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that now the methods `getSrc` and `setSrc` can be used against a Web Resource only when refer to an HTML content.

If the Web Resource is an image, the crm will use an `img` tag to display the picture.

If you want to make that code working you need to retrieve the `img` element and assign the `src` property manually:

instead of

```
profilePictureElement.setSrc("data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + body);
```

you need to write

```js
var profilePicture = document.getElementById("WebResource_ProfilePicture");
profilePicture.setAttribute("src","data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + body);
```

note: **this is an unsupported customization**